# How to pass a variable from Express to a Jade template

Tags: node.js, variables, express, pug

I've already seen a bunch of answers about this but none that covers the whole process. I'm really out of ideas.

Here is my code:

**express code**

```
res.render('index', {expressVar:"My Great Example"});
```

**template.jade**

```
doctype html

block vars

html
    head

    body
        | #{working}

        | #{notWorking}

        | #{notWorking2}
```

**index.jade**

```
extends template.jade

- var localVar = "Other Example"

block vars
    - var working     = "This is working"
    - var notWorking  = expressVar
    - var notWorking2 = localVar
```

What i'really trying to do is to get both variables that are not working to get printed inside the template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Darren Schnare wrote an article that explains how to figure this out:
http://darrenschnare.com/blog/2013/08/14/sharing-variables-with-jade-templates/

You need to place all markup in a root block then declare variables in this block in the template. All variables will be accessible to each scope that is a child of the the scope.

**template.jade**

```
doctype html

block page
    html
        head

        body
            | #{working}

            | #{notWorking}

            | #{notWorking2}
```

**index.jade**

```
extends template

- localVar = "Other Example"

prepend page
    - working     = "This is working"
    - notWorking  = expressVar
    - notWorking2 = localVar
```

Comment: Nice article. Thanks a lot, Bob.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer but lets say my jade template has an external script like main.js, how do I access #{working} in that file